# Converting DEM to point file gives ERROR 000870?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, interpolation

I have a DEM which has noisy parts to it. I am trying to (eventually) calculate the volume. However when I do cut/fill, there are obviously white sections where it hasn't been able to calculate the noisy parts. To get around this I was going to interpolate my DEM with one of the interpolate tools (IDW/Kriging/NN/Spline etc)

Problem: It has to be point file, so I was converting raster to point file when error 000870 appear stating that I already have an output file with the same name. I definitely don't and I have turned overwrite on just in case.

I was then going to convert back convert back to raster to do the volume.

Can anyone think of a simpler way or solve my mysterious file problem?

Using ArcGIS 10. All extensions possible, cannot download additional programs due to being on a university computer and not having admin rights.

[image: Noisy DEM]

Comment: How noisy is your noise? Are there large spikes in your DEM?

Comment: There aren't spikes, but it is in ArcScene at the moment so it is in 3D. There are are a lot of large gaps (holes?) in the DEM. I've attached a picture above - you can see through the DEM on to the coloured plane (I have removed one quarter so you can see cut/fill below) as well as the white in the cut/fill.

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this answer by saying I haven't tried this suggestion but it should work. If you have 3D Analyst, you will be converting 'Raster to Multipoint' or 'Raster to TIN' followed by reversing it back to raster using 'TIN to Raster'. This will give the data void several large triangle faces that will be stretching from one side of the void to the other side with interpolating z-values. The last step will rasterize these triangle faces and interpolating the data void. This is an ad hoc solution and there might be a better way but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I am giving it a go now. My DEM is huge so it will take a while!

Comment: keep me and @Barbarossa up to date :)

Comment: So, my DEM is about 7GB...I have run the raster-TIN conversion for 5 hours. Do you know if it is supposed to take this long?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? the answer is not enough information. TINning will take a **very** long time. Can you fill your gaps with con http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Con/009z00000005000000/ and focalmean http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000qs000000.htm.

Comment: How do you find out the string length? I am fairly new to Arc, but am not a computer person generally. Trying to learn quickly! I think the focal mean might work...i'm trying this now.

Comment: There are raster processing tools that I run that I start Friday afternoon and let it run over the weekend and still might not be finished by Monday morning so yes 5 hours is not that unusual. If you have access to a workstation or server with lots of RAM, 16+G RAM and up, I would use that. I believe Windows 7 supports 32 G. Let me know how it works.